# No onCreate and onStart methods

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

i've created a android library project from the actionbarsherlock sources 4.4.0.
I imported the library in my application project. Next i'd liked to extend the SherlockFragmentActivity class, as described in many tutorials.

In my class, that extends the SherlockFragmentActivity class, i cannot override the onCreate and onStart methods, because, they are not available...
If i open the source of SherlockFragmentActivity, i could reference the onCreate and the onStart methods...

If i open my class in the Type-Hierarchy, Watson > SherlockFragmentActivity > MyActivity is displayed. But if i open the source of watson, i see, that it extends FragmentActivity. Why are the methods of FragmentActivity not available?

Here is the code snippet

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;


public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

What's going wrong?

Thanks Mario

Comment: Show how you are trying to override the methods.

Comment: On a side note - is there a reason to use ActionBarSherlock? The Android v7 support library provides Action Bar capability back to Android v2.1.

Comment: I've added a code sample

Comment: You have to add @Override above each method.

Comment: dosn't help, error message says: "The method onStart() of type MyActivity must override or implement a supertype method", so the method is not available from the supertype

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your project setup. With the two methods you show, adding @Override should work. I don't know if it will help but you could try using Clean on the project. Other than that all I could suggest would be to create a new project from scratch.